# Finding 3rd Child of an url when url for 1st and 2nd children are already known in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, url, beautifulsoup

I am doing a project in python. I have an url, lets say http://funny.moa-times.net/o/medal/abcdefg.html
There is another url like this http://funny.moa-times.net/o/medal/mnopqrs.html. So both these urls are child of /medal/( or as I thought). Now there is another child url such as

http://funny.moa-times.net/o/medal/something_else.html. I need to find out what is this something_else

I have tried this:

```
`import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = 'http://funny.moa-times.net/'
grab = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(grab.text, 'html.parser')

# opening a file in write mode
f = open("test1.txt", "w")
# traverse paragraphs from soup
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
  data = link.get('href')
  f.write(data)
  f.write("\n")

f.close()
`
```

this code gave me only 1 url http://www.moa-times.net/. when I applied the same code on this url, like

```
urls = 'http://www.moa-times.net/'
```

it gave me about 100 different urls. None of them had the /o/medal/ format

I have also tried the above code with

```
urls = 'http://funny.moa-times.net/o/medal/'
```

it gave me error stating that

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 545
    warnings.warn(
XMLParsedAsHTMLWarning: It looks like you're parsing an XML document using an HTML parser. If this really is an HTML document (maybe it's XHTML?), you can ignore or filter this warning. If it's XML, you should know that using an XML parser will be more reliable. To parse this document as XML, make sure you have the lxml package installed, and pass the keyword argument `features="xml"` into the BeautifulSoup constructor.
```

but when I tried to use xml parser

```
import csv
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('http://storage.moj-posao.net/o/hunt/')
```

it gave me:

```
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1218, in parse
    tree.parse(source, parser)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1520.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 569, in parse
    source = open(source, "rb")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
```

I have also looked at the source code of the webpage

http://funny.moa-times.net/

this is what I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="refresh"
   content="0; url=https://www.moa-times.net/">
</head>
<body>
   <p>The page has moved to:
   <a href="https://www.moa-times.net/">MoaTimes</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

when I click

```
http://funny.moa-times.net/o/medal/
```

it shows:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>MDN78TCSTK8T79QY</RequestId>
    <HostId>u5r0MIS2UNf4Cqm2gZNpaZqvTrOCgIG/0IRq10uk2ndkZlALPKgp+vEcnxooid7njxeHkrkB14s=</HostId>
    </Error>
```

No it's not password protected. and we do not need to login to access this. Just need to change the "something_else" part

I am fairly new at web scraping. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.